# Exclusive tests in forge

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge

Is there a way to run individual tests in forge? looking for a behavior similar to '.only' in mocha

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

You can use `forge test --match-contract $YourContractName`
or even `forge test --match` where, for exemple, if you use `--match mint`, forge will execute all tests that have 'mint' in their function name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way we can do 
forge test --match-contract $YourContractName --match <FunctionName>
I want to test specific function of this contract

Comment: this might help ```forge test --match-test yourFunctionName```

https://book.getfoundry.sh/faq?highlight=match-test#how-do-i-run-specific-tests

Answer (score 3):

For individual tests i use:

```
 forge test --match-path test/functional/**/$(TEST_NAME)\*
```

This runs TEST_NAME in any subfolder after the the path test/functional

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to just test a specific **function** try this:

```
forge test --match-test yourFunctionName
```

For more visit [foundry faq](https://book.getfoundry.sh/faq?highlight=match-test#how-do-i-run-specific-tests)